# Как правильно очистить и перезаписать массив в Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx

При клике на кнопку я получаю value инпута и массив элементов

```
<button onClick={()=>this.props.test(this.props.value,this.props.pokemonList)}>Push</button>
```

в action я перебираю его и сравниваю value input-a с типом в масиве и если они совпадают записываю в state

```
export function filterByTypes(searchValue,pokList){
    return (dispatch) =>{
        dispatch(getValue(searchValue));
        pokList.map((types)=>
        types.types.map((name)=>{
            if (searchValue == name.type.name){
                dispatch(filteredPokes(types));
            }})
        );
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
   case FILTERED_POKES:
      return{
         ...state, filteredPokes: [...state,action.types]
     }
```

Мне нужно чтобы при каждом клике filteredPokes очищался  и заново заполнялся
Я пробовал делать вот так ...state, filteredPokes: [action.types], но тогда в масив записывается только один элемент.
Подскажите как это исправить или сделать правильную проверку.
Спасибо

Comment: Вам нужно правильно оформить вопрос - добавьте пример как выглядит ваш `state` в redux и пример какие значения приходят `this.props.value,this` `props.pokemonList`. Где вы вызываете `filterByTypes` и зачем вы там два раза исполняете `.map`?

Comment: Это не столь важно, мне всего лишь нужно чтобы массив который уже заполнен при клике очищался и заполнялся новыми элементами. В React я би сделал проверку но в Redux не понимаю как Это сделать.с самого начала у меня массив пустой, затем он заполняется елементами.Це все працюе.Але дальше при клике мне нужно чтобы он очистился и заполнился новыми елементами.Але у меня визодило сделать только так что в иснуюючий массив добвалялися еще элементы.

Comment: А как вы собираетесь получить ответ тогда, если задать вопрос правильно и конкретно для вас не столь важно? В таком случае получить ответ, который поможет решить вашу проблему, вам не столь важно получается.

Comment: Очевидно у вас баг в самом редюсере, к тому же вероятнее всего вы неправильно отсылаете действия в редакс судя по коду выше. Но так как вы не хотите внести ясности, то и отклик на ваш вопрос будет соответствующий